# Where is the source code for usb_storage in linux

Tags: linux, usb

In linux , whenever I plug in a pen drive the modprobe utility automatically loads the required module into the kernel. But I would like to know where is the source code for this module(I have downloaded the entire linux kernel source but am still unable to find it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is under drivers/usb/storage/: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/usb/storage